# How do I parse string data from a JSON object passed to a js server?

Tags: json, node.js, socket.io

Here is my client side based on Android code (libgdx) -

```
   public static void updateTheServer() {
   JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try {
        data.put("roomName", tf.getText()); //tf is a textbox i take input from
        socket.emit("joinRoom",data);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Gdx.app.log("SOCKET.IO", "Error sending room name data");
    }
}
```

here is my server code on javascript/nodejs-

```
         var clientInfo={}; //key-Value Pairs
         var roomName;
    io.on('connection', function (socket){
    socket.emit('socketID',{id:socket.id});
    socket.on('joinRoom',function(data){
             data.id=socket.id;
             console.log("Got room name!");
             if(!roomName===null){
             roomName=data.JSON.parse(roomName);
             clientInfo[socket.id]=roomName;
             socket.join(roomName);

    }

});
```

The error I get in the command window is- "TypeError : Cannot read property 'roomName' of undefined at Socket.

Can you tell me how to solve this problem? My objective is to get roomname form the client so i can make them join that particular room!

Im confused as to how to acheive this when the platforms are different, client is java and server is js.

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking whether roomName is null, the thing with javascript is that it has multiple null-like types. Undefined being one of them which is what roomName is set to, roomName is not defined. You are only checking if it's null, which it isnt. It's undefined.

You create the roomName property at the top but you never assign anything to it, so it is undefined. Change your if statement to this:

```
// This will return false if roomName is null, undefined or 0.
if(!roomName) {
    // your code
}

// or alternatively, change the assignment of roomName to
roomName = null;
```

But i suggest assigning something to roomName before trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks i think that part of the problem is solved now! Thankyou